# Receiving "Subscript out of range" error when using .formula

Tags: excel, vba

I keep receiving a **"subscript out of range"** error when running the following code. When I change "Sheet1" to the name of the actual worksheet, I receive an **"Application-defined or Object-defined"** error.

This is the line that I receive the error:

```
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCnt, "CK" & iCnt).Formula = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCnt, "CK" & iCnt).Formula
```

The aim of this code is to "copy" a row from a closed workbook to another workbook *if* the value of the column in that row equals "test".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call ReadDataFromCloseFile

    End Sub

    Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile()
    On Error GoTo Errorcatch
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Worksheets("myworkbook").Range("A8:CK9999").Clear

Dim src As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim iTotalRows As Integer
Dim iCnt As Integer

Set src = Workbooks.Open("mysourceworkbook.xlsm", True, True)
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

iTotalRows = src.Worksheets("sourceworksheet").Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count

For iCnt = 8 To iTotalRows
    If src.Worksheets("sourceworksheet").Range("E" & iCnt).Value = "test" Then
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCnt, "CK" & iCnt).Formula = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCnt, "CK" & iCnt).Formula
    Else
    End If
Next iCnt

src.Close False
Set src = Nothing

Range("A8:CK9999").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
Application.Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Finished!"

    Errorcatch:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation

    End Sub
```

Comment: Presumably `Worksheets("Sheet1")` is in `ThisWorkbook`. You should specify that.

Comment: What @BigBen said, or at least qualify it to it's respective workbook, whichever that is.

Comment: Additionally: Make sure you specify a workbook and worksheet infront of **every** `Range` or `Cells` (there are many in your code where no workbook and no worksheet is specified). Best is to always have a full referenece Workbook -> Worksheet -> Range

Comment: Unfortunately, I still receive a "subscript out of range" error. I have used ThisWorkbook in the actual line and also tried defining it as a variable. @BigBen

Comment: Is each sheet actually named `"Sheet1"`? If you're referring to a worksheet by name, you need to use its *actual* name. Are you trying to transfer formulas over or values? What do your formulas look like and do they contain references to other workbook(s)?

Comment: I have used the actual names and I get the **Application defined or object-defined** error. When I use ´´Worksheets(1)´´, I get the **Subscript out of range** error.

Comment: @Xequ please reference every range and cells with a worksheet and a workbook and update the code in your question.

Comment: I set ´wb´ as ´ThisWorkbook´ and changed the affected line to 'wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & iCnt, "CK" & iCnt).Formula = src.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & iCnt, "CK" & iCnt).Formula' It now works perfectly. Thank you for your help!